# Perl: Getting STDERR of system call, separately from STDOUT

Tags: perl

It is usually enough for me in Perl, to get a single string that contains STDOUT combined with STDERR. I do it this way:

```
my $stdout_and_stderr = `$cmd 2>&1`;
```

But now I need it in 2 separate strings - one for STDOUT and one for STDERR.

How can I do it in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );
run3 [ 'sh', '-c', $cmd ], undef, my $stdout, my $stderr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Open3;

my $cmd = 'ls -la';

my $pid = open3(\*WRITER, \*READER, \*ERROR, $cmd);
#if \*ERROR is 0, stderr goes to stdout

while( my $output = <READER> )
{
    print "output->$output";
}

while( my $errout = <ERROR> )
{
    print "err->$errout";
}

waitpid( $pid, 0 ) or die "$!\n";
my $retval =  $?;
print "retval-> $retval\n";
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great. Also thank you for the detailed and full example

Comment: This program suffers from a race condition. If the child outputs a lot to STDERR, both programs will lock up. Use IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run instead.

Comment: @ikegami, thank you for your important note. Can you please write here your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a simpler way to catch only STDERR. Catch STDERR and throw STDOUT away:

```
$output = `cmd 2>&1 1>/dev/null`;
```

You can also do the opposite - throw STDERR away, such that it is even not printed to the shell:

```
$output = `cmd 2>/dev/null`;
```

If you need to catch both of them separately, use one of the other answers in this thread. They are very good

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though (and therefore shouldn't be the accepted answer). The question was how to capture STDOUT and STDERR separately. Your answer ignores STDOUT and only captures STDERR.